# Having problem testing a form submission with attached file with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, cuprite

Ruby in Rails.

I have a form where can upload an image in a file type input field along with other 3 text fields.

Everything works like a charm in production, development and so.
BUT when I run a test that fills out those fields AND attach an image with `attach_file` and then hit the Submit button... the request never makes it to the controller method.

It goes to the root path '/' and shows nothing but a white and blank screen.
And obviously the test fails.

**If I attach nothing but the text fields then the request makes it to the controller.**

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara', '~> 3.35', '>= 3.35.3'
gem 'cuprite', '~> 0.13'
gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 6.1'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
```

spec.rb

```
require 'system_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Organization', type: :system do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  signed_in_as :user

  scenario 'User creates an organization with photo', js: true do
    visit new_organization_path

    fill_in 'organization[name]', with: 'Foo'
    fill_in 'organization[location]', with: 'Bar'
    fill_in 'organization[info]', with: 'Baz'

    # If this is commented the request goes successfully to the controller.
    page.attach_file(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/images/image.PNG')) do
      page.find('span', text: 'No File Selected').click
    end

    click_on 'Create Organization'

    # Should be redirected to this organization's view
    expect(page).to have_content 'Foo'
  end
end
```

Rails version: 6.1.4
Ruby: 3.1.3

Comment: in order to submit the form, you're clicking on a span element with text "No File Selected" (doesn't seem right), but in your description you say that you're clicking the Submit button (this seems like the correct trigger for form submission).